# Cpanel: putting a custom directory in /etc/httpd

Tags: mod-perl

I need some custom filters for Apache, so I wrote a mod_perl module MyFilter and put this in /etc/httpd. However, 24 hours later, cpanel seems to remove all 'unkown' directories from /etc/httpd. How do I prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I received the answer from cpanel support;

You could create the directory in /usr/local/"your directory", then create a symlink as follows.

```
mkdir /usr/local/MyFilter
ln -s /usr/local/MyFilter /usr/local/apache/MyFilter
chmod 755 /usr/local/MyFilter
```

Then create the hook script /scripts/posteasyapache with a bash command inside it to recreate the above symlink anytime Apache is rebuilt. Then set the posteasyapache script executable "chmod +x /scripts/posteasyapache"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to `/usr/local/apache` ?

Also, where did you put the config includes? The proper place is `/usr/local/apache/conf/include/` files. For example, in `/usr/local/apache/conf/include/pre_main_2.conf`